# What is the best way to cluster varnish?

Tags: nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

I need to have 3 varnish instances, I follow this guide [creating-varnish-cluster](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/creating-self-routing-varnish-cluster?success=true) and now I have those systems

- 3 servers that have varnish, each varnish has vcl like that [vcl-cluster](https://gist.github.com/hoseinabedi71/884a7b14666b3a2f5898132567951c5c)
- 1 backend server, that contains application and Nginx for load balancing between varnish servers, Nginx config: [nginx-config](https://gist.github.com/hoseinabedi71/a8e222f16b6405601735e76542bd87e4)

but requests received in Nginx and passes through varnish but varnish server can't forward request to the backend. when I call directly backend it perfectly works.

how can I fix this issue? and is there any better solution for varnish scaling? (except varnish plus:D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`server.identity` is the hostname of the machine, by default. I assume your machines are not called `node1`, `node2` and `node3`, so you need to edit your VCL to reflect that.